# Samesite:Strict still sends the cookie

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, cookies, samesite

I am trying samesite:strict, but it is not working at all,

Server1 (*running on http://localhost:5000/*):

```js
const express = require('express');
const cookieParser = require('cookie-parser');
var logger = require("morgan");

const app = express();
app.use(cookieParser());
app.use(logger("dev"));

app.get('/', (req, res) => {
    res.cookie('mycookie', 'omarhadidi', {
        sameSite: 'strict'
    });
    res.sendFile('./server.html', {root:__dirname})
})
app.post('/delete-user', (req, res) => {
    console.log('cookies :>> ', req.cookies);
    res.send('I am hacked')
})

app.listen(5000, () => console.log("Server Listening on port 5000"));
```

Server2 (*running by VSCode LiveServer on http://localhost:3000/hack.html*):

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>

<body>
    <p id="data"></p>
    <form action="http://localhost:5000/delete-user" method="post">
        <input type="submit" value="Hack">
    </form>
    <script>
        console.log('cookies :>> ', document.cookie);
        const form = document.querySelector("form")
        // form.submit();  I cancelled Here to try to submit it manually using submit button
    </script>
</body>

</html>
```

### The Problem:

When I send a `GET` request to `http://localhost:5000/`, `mycookie` is set, but also it is sent when I send a `POST` to `http://localhost:5000/delete-user` from the form in `http://localhost:3000/hack.html`. And "sent" here means logged by `console.log('cookies :>> ', req.cookies);` written in **Server 1**

Comment: but is it SET in the cookie storage for localhost:3000 under host localhost:5000

Comment: You mean in (developer tools>Application tab>Storage>Cookies) right? Yes it is. And it shows it is samesite strict too

Comment: `http://localhost:5000` and `http://localhost:3000` are different _origins_, but they are the same _site_, because site considers only the protocol (`http:`) and the top-level domain, not the port.

Comment: Oh! That's a big point. Thank you @HeikoTheißen . I will read about them more

Comment: Add a domain to your hosts file. Something like `127.0.0.1   domain1` and use that for testing: `http://domain1:3000` and `http://localhost:5000`. Here is a guide for Windows: https://www.howtogeek.com/784196/how-to-edit-the-hosts-file-on-windows-10-or-11/

Comment: Oh thanks @chrwahl I will read that inshallah